# How can I debug the scripts on my web page using the Chrome browser developer tools?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have no problem going to Sources, selecting a file and then adding breakpoints for files which are loaded in one by one. But I have some javascript on my web page within  tags. How can I view, debug this? I think I have tried everything but I still can't get those few lines of code to appear in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

go to sources then in pane below it you have a icon (top left) click on that and select file u need to debug

Comment: The file I need to debug is my web page and that's the one that's not in the list :-(

Comment: use `localhost/folder/index.htm` instead of  `localhost/folder/` as url it will show the web page in sources too

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, under sources, there is an option to view the actual web page itself.  You select that, then find the inline script on that page and set a breakpoint there.

Comment: Sorry but I don't see that option :-( Where is it ?  I see two tabs: Sources and Content Scripts only.

Comment: @SamanthaJ - In the `Sources` tab, you expand the line with your page's domain in it and then there will be an option with your page's path and under that will be an item with your page's filename.

Answer (score 0):

Add in your source this code: `debugger;`
This will automatically stop during debug in your Chrome developer tools.

Comment: Thanks but I can't really keep changing my source code. Is there no way I can bring up the source HTML with script tags inside?

Comment: you can, put inside script tag this: debugger; and open a Chrome Developer tools.